# Double subscript error using tensor package

Tags: errors, tensor

I have been attempting to typeset tensors using the [tensor](http://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/tensor/tensor.pdf) package and have come across an error when attempting to create subscripts on the subscripts of my tensors.

An example of this would be the following:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{tensor-symmetrize}
T\indices{_{(\mu_1 \mu_2 \cdots \mu_n)}_\rho^\sigma} = \frac{1}{n!} (T \indices{_{\mu_1}_{\mu_2}}_{\cdots}_{\mu_n}_\rho^\sigma 
+ \text{sum over permutations of indices}) .
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

On compiling this document I get an error saying

```
! Double subscript.
l.8 ...frac{1}{n!} (T \indices{_{\mu_1}_{\mu_2}}_
                                              {\cdots}_{\mu_n}_\rho^\sig...
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).  Thanks for providing a working example of the error you found.  In the future, please trim it down (as I have) to be a [*minimal* example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)—it should be as small as possible but still exhibit the problem you have.  This makes it more readable, and ultimately, more answerable.

Comment: Sorry about the size of the example! I'll make sure to keep it as concise as possible next time. Thank you so much for editing it down for me. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a misbalance in braces:

```
\begin{equation} \label{tensor-symmetrize}
T\indices{_{(\mu_1 \mu_2 \cdots \mu_n)}_\rho^\sigma} = \frac{1}{n!} (T \indices{_{\mu_1}_{\mu_2}_{\cdots}_{\mu_n}_\rho^\sigma }
+ \text{sum over permutations of indices}) .
\end{equation}
```

You could take out the extra braces and subscripts on the right-hand side like this:

```
\begin{equation} 
T\indices{_{(\mu_1 \mu_2 \cdots \mu_n)}_\rho^\sigma} = \frac{1}{n!} (T \indices{_{\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_n}_\rho^\sigma }
+ \text{sum over permutations of indices})
\end{equation}
```

[image: sample code output]

Comment: Sorry this is so trivial. I really should have seen that myself, although the error was somewhat misleading. Thank you so much.

Comment: @James: Your upvote and check are thanks enough.

Answer (score 2):

Another way is hiding the "inner indices".

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tensor}

\newcommand{\cind}[2]{#1_{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation} \label{tensor-symmetrize}
T\indices{_{(\cind{\mu}{1} \cind{\mu}{2} \cdots \cind{\mu}{n})}_\rho^\sigma} =
\frac{1}{n!} (T \indices{_{\cind{\mu}{1}}_{\cind{\mu}{2}}_{\cdots}_{\cind{\mu}{n}}_\rho^\sigma}
+ \text{sum over permutations of indices}) .
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Defining a new command for it certainly helps with the clarity of the source. Thanks, I'll keep this in mind.